# Replace a page with a BottomNavigationBar (Tabview) with another page on navigation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have implemented an app which navigate through few screens and the main point is a BottomNavigationBar with four tabs. Inside the second tab. I have a ModalBottomSheet that has a button option to logout. The idea is to navigate back to Login page after logout button clicked.
well it does navigate back to login screen but it takes the BottomNavigationBar with it.

I will provide my navigation stack view and the bottom navigation bar main page.

***Login to the BottomNavigationBar Page***

```
Navigator.of(context).push(PageTransition(
                    child: ProHomeScreen(),
                    type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                  ));
```

***The BottomNavigationBar main page***

```
class ProHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProHomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  static String tag = 'pro-home-page';

  @override
  _ProHomeScreenState createState() => _ProHomeScreenState();
}

class _ProHomeScreenState extends State<ProHomeScreen>with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<int> _history = [0];
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  TabController _tabController;
  List<Widget> mainTabs;
  List<BuildContext> navStack = [null, null, null, null];
  //
  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
    mainTabs = <Widget>[
      Navigator(
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings){
            return PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context, animiX, animiY) { // use page PageRouteBuilder instead of 'PageRouteBuilder' to avoid material route animation
              navStack[0] = context;
              return DailyGuideScreen();
            });
          }),
      Navigator(
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings){
            return PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context, animiX, animiY) {  // use page PageRouteBuilder instead of 'PageRouteBuilder' to avoid material route animation
              navStack[1] = context;
              return UserProfileViewScreen();
            });
          }),
      Navigator(
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings){
            return PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context, animiX, animiY) {  // use page PageRouteBuilder instead of 'PageRouteBuilder' to avoid material route animation
              navStack[2] = context;
              return PetProfileViewScreen();
            });
          }),
      Navigator(
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings){
            return PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context, animiX, animiY) {  // use page PageRouteBuilder instead of 'PageRouteBuilder' to avoid material route animation
              navStack[3] = context;
              return AllMealPlanPage();
            });
          }),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
  //
  final List<BottomNavigationBarRootItem> bottomNavigationBarRootItems = [
    BottomNavigationBarRootItem(
      bottomNavigationBarItem: BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: Text(''),
      ),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarRootItem(
      bottomNavigationBarItem: BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        title: Text(''),
      ),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarRootItem(
      bottomNavigationBarItem: BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.pets),
        title: Text(''),
      ),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarRootItem(
      bottomNavigationBarItem: BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.fastfood),
        title: Text(''),
      ),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: mainTabs,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: bottomNavigationBarRootItems.map((e) => e.bottomNavigationBarItem).toList(),
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Color(0xFF03B898),
          unselectedItemColor: Color(0xFF01816B),
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
          // indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
          //   borderSide: BorderSide(color: lightGreen, width: 5.0),
          //   insets: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 44.0),
          // ),
        ),
      ),
      onWillPop: () async{
        if (Navigator.of(navStack[_tabController.index]).canPop()) {
          Navigator.of(navStack[_tabController.index]).pop();
          setState((){ _selectedIndex = _tabController.index; });
          return false;
        }else{
          if(_tabController.index == 0){
            setState((){ _selectedIndex = _tabController.index; });
            SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop'); // close the app
            return true;
          }else{
            _tabController.index = 0; // back to first tap if current tab history stack is empty
            setState((){ _selectedIndex = _tabController.index; });
            return false;
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    _tabController.index = index;
    setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
}
}

////

class BottomNavigationBarRootItem {
  final String routeName;
  final NestedNavigator nestedNavigator;
  final BottomNavigationBarItem bottomNavigationBarItem;

  BottomNavigationBarRootItem({
    @required this.routeName,
    @required this.nestedNavigator,
    @required this.bottomNavigationBarItem,
  });
}

abstract class NestedNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  NestedNavigator({Key key, @required this.navigatorKey}) : super(key: key);
}

class HomeNavigator extends NestedNavigator {
  HomeNavigator({Key key, @required GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey})
      : super(
    key: key,
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        WidgetBuilder builder;
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/':
            builder = (BuildContext context) => AllMealPlanPage();
            break;
          case '/home/1':
            builder = (BuildContext context) => MealPlanDetailsScreen();
            break;
          default:
            throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
        }
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: builder,
          settings: settings,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
////
```

***Second Tab The Logout option Navigation(which is inside a ModalBottomSheet)***

```
_userProfileBtmSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
... 
).whenComplete(() {
      if(goLogOut){
        _isLoading ? null : _handleLogout(context);
      }
    });
  }

////

Within _handleLogout()

Navigator.pop(
        context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
```

I need to navigate out from the BottomNavigationBar page and replace the screen with the login screen.

```
https://github.com/jasonwaku/jason_pawfect/tree/master
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
Navigator.pop(
    context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
```

Try using

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacment(
    context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
```

Comment: it does go back to the login screen. But with the bottom navigation bar under it.

Comment: when I try to add and logout multiple users the above thing happens again and again. and every time a new bottom navigation bar is stacked on top the previous bottom navigation bar inside the login screen.

Comment: @JasonWaku which login method you are using

Comment: this is the login method 
```Navigator.of(context).push(PageTransition(
                    child: ProHomeScreen(),
                    type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                  ));```

Comment: @JasonWaku I want to see your full code is it on git hub

Comment: @JasonWaku your project is not there only readme and licence file is there

Comment: @JasonWaku and please must check my question also if you have solution for it

Comment: I don't have a solution for it , still could not find a way to solve.

Comment: @JasonWaku ok no worry but  your project is not there only readme and licence file is there

Comment: I had uploaded and updated the GitHub @yasir you can have a look if you can. would be very much helpful.

Comment: https://github.com/jasonwaku/jason_pawfect/tree/master please reference here

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue today where I have to go to login page from one of the tab through logout button, and bottom navigation bar also passed along, what i have done is used bloc state management and navigate from navigation bar page according to the state generated by authentication bloc.

logout button:

```
await BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationCubit>(context).logout();
```

authentication cubit:

```
    Future<void> logout() async {
    emit(AuthenticationLoadingState());
    await userRepository.logout();
    emit(UnAutheticatedState());
  }
```

And listen to the Unauthenticated state in bloc listner widget in the home page of navigation bar

```
    Scaffold(
          body: BlocListener<AuthenticationCubit, AuthenticationState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is UnautheticatedState) {
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<dynamic>(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => Login(),
                  ),
                  (route) =>
                      false, //if you want to disable back feature set to false
                );
              }
            },
```